# Trying to install tryton 5.4 on ubuntu 18.04 Error is the select field (drop-down) for database field on browser with Sao

Tags: python, ubuntu, tryton

I had finished installing trytond 5.4 and sao with out error on ubuntu 18.04 server

But when open my browser and put server-ip:8000 tryton -> open database select field and text field username

But the error is the select field (drop-down) for database not working and i cant see my database name that i had been created on postgresql

and i had made browse and grunt for sao all done 
So i cant open tryton ERP
Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize your database after you created it on the backed in order to be shown on the list of databases of the server. Here is the section of the doumentation which explains how to do it:

https://docs.tryton.org/projects/server/en/latest/topics/setup_database.html#topics-setup-database

Once you've initialized your database you have to restart the server to refresh the list of databases. Then you can access the database using admin user and the password you entered on the init process.